# Rearranging File Structure Throwing "Element type is invalid" Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm reorganizing the code in my application into a bunch of sub-folders. I'm moving a top-nav component into a subfolder called navigation, this component makes up part of a 'main-nav' container. However, when I shift top-nav into the new folder I start getting the following erro

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>   Check the render method of `TopNavTemplate`.

I've been reading through a lot of threads and I can't figure out why shifting the poisition would cause this. I've made sure that the component is pointing to the appropriate imports within the file restructure (these errors get thrown before the current error anyway, so it at least thinks that it's pulling everything in correctly.) I also don't think it's a syntax error in the import statement - I'm connecting the top-nav to my redux store as a default export, and I'm not importing it between {}.

Code for the top-nav export can be found below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ClickOutside from 'react-click-outside';
import {IconSprite} from '../general/icons.js';
import {Modal} from './modal.js';
import {HeaderSelect} from './select.js';
//Import statements that connect TopNav to the redux store
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions/actionCreator.js';
import { bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import logo from '../../logo.svg';


export class TopNavTemplate extends React.Component {
//Render function and a bunch of code goes here
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    selectedTarget: state.selectedTarget,
    availableTargets: state.availableTargets,
    modal: state.modal,
    currentUser: state.currentUser,
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

const TopNav = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TopNavTemplate);

export default TopNav;
```

I then import the TopNav into my main-nav layout like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import TopNav from '../components/navigation/top-nav.js';
import {SideNav} from '../components/side-nav.js';

export class MainNav extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return ([
            <TopNav />,
            <SideNav />
        ])
    }
  }
```

If I change the import statement to pull from the old version of the file

> import TopNav from ../components/top-nav.js

everything works like a charm. I've even tried removing that file to prevent any kind of web-pack confusion but that doesn't seem to the issue. For some reason, moving this file into a different folder is now causing the export to be undefined instead of a proper react component? Feeling very lost.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a very stupid mistake - I'd forgotten to save one of the files I was importing while shifting everything around. For some reason this wasn't throwing an error that the import couldn't be found, and was instead causing the wrapped connect component to return as undefined.